# In IOS the Popup windows closes while trying to use firebase authentication (signInWithPopup method)

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, wkwebview

I have a react app where i enabled the firebase authentication feature and it works fine and then i use wkwebview to build the ios app from this react app. Everything works except when i click sign in google  btn the popup window opens and then closes after 10 seconds with a response code auth/popup-closed-by-use. But it works fine in android and web.

i use firebase authentication feature there is a code example

```
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }.catch(e=>{
            console.log(e)
        })
```